# Is it possible to automatically inject the request into model methods?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

"Why do you need this for?", you may ask.
Well, it's a very common scenario in Django.

Following the rule "thin views, fat models", one is very encouraged to place within models all the logic related to models. Therefore, it is very common to place within models all those methods to check whether the current user has permission to perform certain action to a given instance of the model.

This may ring a bell to you:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def allow_editing(self, user):
        ...

    def allow_super_awkward_action(self, user):
        ...
```

All this hoping to be able to do something like this in templates:

```
{% if object.allow_super_awkward_action %}
   place some link to go to the super awkward action
{% endif %}
```

Problem is: how do you pass the current user to that method call, if Django won't let you do it? This code will hopelessly fail, and one will end up following one of the alternate paths:

- Call the method in the view, store the result in a variable, pass the variable into the template context, and then check against the variable. Long way to go, imagine you need to do this for several model methods, on several views (this may not be a pure DRY violation, but is very close.)
- Create a template filter to pass arbitrary arguments to a function. I don't think it will even work, since filters will get the result of the evaluated function (not the function itselt), and it will be too late at that point.
- Create a template tag to call a function passing arbitrary arguments to it. This is possible, but then again, good luck implemeting the "as" behaviour so that you can use the computed result inside `if` templatetags.

So, what if it was possible to automatically inject `request.user` into the function at the moment of calling it. Or better! What if you could inject the whole `request` object? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, and it came to me in the form of a decorator.
It's a little bit obscure, I know, but we are in Python, and Python allow for a lil bit of darkness ;)

This one here searches the stack frames for an instance of `HttpRequest` and if it finds it, it will inject it into the decorated function.
(If you are wondering, assertions are there to help you code defensively: a request object might not be found, or the function call could still fail in a template if extra arguments don't have default values, etc.)

```
import inspect
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.utils import six

def inject_request(func):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    assert 'request' in argspec.args, \
        "There must be a 'request' argument in the function."
    index = argspec.args.index('request')
    assert index in [0, 1], \
        "The 'request' argument must be, at most, the second positional argument."
    assert len(argspec.args) - len(argspec.defaults or []) == index, \
        "All arguments after (and including) 'request' must have default values."
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if (index < len(args) and args[index]) or kwargs.get('request', None):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        request = None
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        while frame and not request:
            for v_name, v_object in six.iteritems(frame.f_locals):
                if isinstance(v_object, HttpRequest):
                    request = v_object
                    break
            frame = frame.f_back
        if request:
            kwargs.setdefault('request', request)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

In your models, you can do this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    @inject_request
    def allow_editing(self, request=None):
        ...
    @inject_request
    def allow_super_awkward_action(self, request=None):
        ...
```

And we're back to happiness using the plain method call in templates:

```
{% if object.allow_super_awkward_action %}
    place link to the action
{% endif %}
```

This will work!